# xcode iphone bluetooth chat between device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, navigation, sharing

I want to know if there is a framework or method/technique that will allow me to write an iphone/ipad that will allow one device to act as a "Leader" and the other devices as "Followers" in a shared book reading.

For example:

Device 1: Leader
Device 2: Follower

Device 1: opens an book app and turns to page 11
Device 2: opens the same book app and automatically "follows" device 1 to page 11

This sounds like there needs to be some network communication like bluetooth.. Anyone seen this type of thing done?

Answer (score 1):

first search result for 'iphone bluetooth programming' is [here](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502)

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely the sort of thing [Game Kit's peer-to-peer connectivity](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1) was created for.